# Cant show images with vuejs and cloudshell

Tags: image, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, nuxt.js, google-cloud-shell

```
          <template slot="items"  slot-scope="props">
              <tr>
                  <td><img src='/situation/static/my-images/Teste.png'                                    
                     style = "widht: 251px; height: 209px" ></td>
                  <td>{{props.item.name}}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.desc }}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.cam }}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.rating }}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.price }}</td>
              </tr>
          </template>
```

When I try to run the above code the image doesnt appear in localhost:3000. When i use inspect element in the place where it should be, it shows that the correct place is referenced, but just doesnt show anything. What to do?

Comment: minor type in the "style" attribute - but I doubt that's the problem. type "width" not "widht".   It's an outside chance that the style would default to an unviewable size. worth a try.

Comment: Corrected the typo but still no image unfortunately

Comment: do you see an image frame with empty contents? or nothing at all? (or a variation?)

Comment: When i dont put a directory it shows that it doesnt contain a image(small symbol at top), but when I put a image(like example above) it shows a white retangle(no small symbol at top)

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the image tag. Try to close the image tag as following:

```
<td><img src="/situation/static/my-images/Teste.png" style="width:251px;height:209px;"/></td>
```